# PHP connect to one of 2 MySQL services

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

I have apache+PHP installed on a server 2003 machine. I have 2 versions of MySQL running on the machine, 4.1 (which runs on port 3306) and 5.1 (which runs on port 3307). Now I'm trying to connect to the 5.1 server with the PHP but it will not allow me to start apache when I have 'extension=php_mysqli.dll' un-commented in the php.ini file. I've done some research and from what I've found the problem is caused by multiple installations of MySQL, but I need the 4.1 as I have multiple databases that cannot be converted yet. Does anyone know how I can get around this problem without having to convert my 4.1 databases?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Do the apache error logs show any output when you have that option enabled?

Comment: No, nothing is written in the error log except saying the previous shutdown was unclean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem I fixed it by upgrading to the latest PHP and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to have one version of MySQL on that server to connect to and then have a VM (Virtual machine) within that server hosting the other MySQL version.  This way the server can hold both but they wont necessarily see each other.  You can set up most VMs to allow access through a bridged network interface card.

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing this but I guess its my only choice